# Как оперативно реагировать на input radio?

Tags: input, html, form, javascript, dom

Всего лишь два переключателя:

```
<input type="radio" name="r" value="1" onclick="check()">Даты неизвестны<br>
<input type="radio" name="r" value="2" onclick="check()"><span>Даты известны<span>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

По умолчанию ничего не выбрано, когда выбираем второй, то добавляем поля ввода (до сюда сделал сам):

```
function check() {
    var inp = document.getElementsByName('r');
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        if (inp[i].type == "radio" && inp[i].checked) {
            if (inp[i].value == 1) {
                document.getElementsByName('text1').disabled = true;
            }
            if (inp[i].value == 2) {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input type="date"  name="d1" ><input type="date"  name="d2" >';

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но "типа ошибся и меняем выбор" - добавленное поле не пропадает. Попытка сделать его  неактивным ни к чему не приводит (этого достаточно). Как вытащить `html` из `js`? Как убрать добавленное "по ошибке" поле?

[ссылка на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shilgen/egL035xg/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что в html коде нету элементов с именем 'text1'.
Кроме того, код:

```
document.getElementsByName('text1')
```

возвращает массив элементов и у массива явно нету свойства "disabled".

И как отметили выше, инпуты достаточно сделать изначально скрытыми.

Пример со скрытием/закрытием: http://jsfiddle.net/gbcx09tp/1/

Comment: элемент был - результат не менялся(.. (да, я очень плохо владею JS), а как сделать так, чтобы записи "display: none" - лежали как и положено в css? (если перейти на id -  то наверно просто меняя их, должно получится обращаться к ним...но тут  name )

Comment: Создаешь 2 класса:

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

Изначально диву прописываешь класс hide:

<div id="div1" class="hide">


В обработчике меняешь классы:

document.getElementById("div1").className = 'show'

document.getElementById("div1").className = 'hide'

Обновил пример: http://jsfiddle.net/gbcx09tp/4/

Answer (score 1):

Изменил Ваш код.
https://jsfiddle.net/shilgen/egL035xg/1/
Можно не заполнять инпутами каждый раз элемент `div1`, а просто изначально их сделать скрытыми, а потом показывать/скрывать.